# Service call from angular without hardcoded Host & Port

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have Angular base ui front end and SpringBoot back end in two different wars deployed in same WebSphere server. While invoking any service from angular controller i have to hardcode the host(localhost) and port(8181) within TS file. Is there any way to externalize the hard coded dependency.

> Blockquote

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { User } from '../model/user';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  private usersUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.usersUrl = 'http://localhost:8181/users';
  }

  public findAll(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(this.usersUrl);
  }

  public save(user: User) {
    return this.http.post<User>(this.usersUrl, user);
  }
}
```

Comment: https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an environment file for the configuration

```
environments/environments.dev.ts
environments/environments.test.ts
environments/environments.prod.ts
```

Example:

```
export const environment = {  
  usersApiUrl: 'http://localhost:8181/users'
};
```

and import this configuration in the component ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';  
import { environment } from './../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {  
  constructor() {
    console.log(environment.userApiUrl);
  }
  title = 'Hello Angular!';
}
```

Comment: Can I use any external properties file that consists the service URL? So that if the service URL gets changed we don't need to rebuild the war

Comment: create a JSON file and load that json file in module and use it as a service or constant file

Answer (score 0):

Angular UI and Spring Boot Backend will run on the same port but with different context paths. In this case, you can just call your backend by `/backend-Context/end-point` you don't need to append the host details.